# Split list in a dataframe in multiple columns using one as the header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I got a pandas dataframe with two columns containing a list (length >= 1) at the end. The first one ("`mode`") has a variable which should be appended to the desired header name, the second column ("`res`") contains the data:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([ 
    { 'c1': 850, 'c2': 'Ex', 'c3': 300.0, 'c4': 250, 'mode': [0, 1], 'res': [1.525, 1.321] },
    { 'c1': 850, 'c2': 'Ex', 'c3': 300.0, 'c4': 250, 'mode': [0, 1], 'res': [1.526, 1.311] }
])
```

with the result

```
    c1  c2     c3   c4    mode             res
0  850  Ex  300.0  250  [0, 1]  [1.525, 1.321]
1  850  Ex  300.0  250  [0, 1]  [1.526, 1.311]
```

Is there a better way to split the dataframe `df` to get this desired result

```py
    c1  c2  c3      c4   res_mode_0  res_mode_1
0  850  Ex  300.0   250       1.525       1.321
1  850  Ex  310.0   250       1.526       1.311
```

than using loops?

Comment: Do you want to remove `mode` and `res` from the dataset and want to add two new columns called `res_mode_0` and `res_mode_1` using two values of `res`?

Comment: Yes, these two columns should get dropped! So to say, I want to "expand" the column 'res'.

Comment: `res` list will always have two elements?

Comment: No, 'res' and 'mode' have an arbitrary length, but it's safe to assume that both have the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code. Advantage is it works regardless of the number of elements in the list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ 
    { 'c1': 850, 'c2': 'Ex', 'c3': 300.0, 'c4': 250, 'mode': [0, 1], 'res': [1.525, 1.321] },
    { 'c1': 850, 'c2': 'Ex', 'c3': 300.0, 'c4': 250, 'mode': [0, 1], 'res': [1.526, 1.311] }
])

split_df = pd.DataFrame(df["res"].tolist()).add_prefix("res_mode_")

df = pd.concat([df, split_df], axis=1).drop(["mode", "res"], axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
df

    c1      c2  c3      c4      res_mode_0  res_mode_1
0   850     Ex  300.0   250     1.525       1.321
1   850     Ex  300.0   250     1.526       1.311
```

Comment: Good answer, note that `df.pop()` would skip dropping columns. (see my answer)

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @agentsmith, great to hear. @sy ker, thank you very much! But I think `.add_prefix("res_mode_")` doesn't work then or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more compact solution without `pd.concat()`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'c1': 850, 'c2': 'Ex', 'c3': 300.0, 'c4': 250, 'mode': [0, 1], 'res': [1.525, 1.321]},
    {'c1': 850, 'c2': 'Ex', 'c3': 300.0, 'c4': 250, 'mode': [0, 1], 'res': [1.526, 1.311]}
])

df[['res_mode_0', 'res_mode_1']] = df['res'].tolist()
df = df.drop(["mode", "res"], axis=1)
df

Out[2]: 
    c1  c2     c3   c4  res_mode_0  res_mode_1
0  850  Ex  300.0  250       1.525       1.321
1  850  Ex  300.0  250       1.526       1.311
```

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient way to do it;

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.pop('your_column').values.tolist()), df], axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, you will have to use this on each columns you need to expand.